# Taking difference of time in R

Tags: r, time

I need to substract time i.e T2-T1 but its giving me an error as mentioned below;

```
  > deltaT <- tim[i + 1] - tim[i]
    Error in tim[i + 1] - tim[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Whereas, T1 and T2 are in the form of

```
        "2017-10-12T12:51:29.616"
```

Can anyone please help me in this ? Thank you !

Comment: Convert to proper datetime format. see `?as.POSIXct`

Comment: Please review [mcve]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Look up `dplyr`, `difftime`, and `lead` of dpylr:

You could potentially use something like this:

```
df%>%mutate(timeDiff = difftime(lead(time), time, units = "days"))
```

If you wanted to find the time between two specific dates you would use:

```
date1 <- as.POSIXct("2017-10-12T12:51:29.616", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")  
date2 <- as.POSIXct("2017-10-12T12:51:39.616", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")

timeBetween = difftime(date1,date2, units = "secs")
print(timeBetween)
Time difference of -10 secs
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what is this ?  df%>%mutate

Comment: its the pipe operator. More explanation here http://uc-r.github.io/pipe

Comment: Thank you ! I just want to subtract "2017-10-12T12:51:29.616" from "2017-10-12T12:51:39.616"; thats why i put the question.

Comment: I didn't down-voted you. There are few people who down voted my question and your answer. Its too bad !